# Has anyone tried relating the projective plane to the Riemann Zeta function?

Tags: general-topology, riemann-zeta, projective-geometry, projective-space

I have a very vague intuitive idea which I have been struggling to give a meaningful definition to, and was wondering if this idea I am working on has been tried before.  I apologize if I am unable to formulate these abstract intuitive idea's better than this; I am trying to work on my exposition for this type of question, so any advice is much appreciated.

I want to treat the analytic continuation of the zeta-function as some kind of conformal mapping between two regions, $A$ $B$ of the complex plane, with $\zeta : A \rightarrow B$, which satisfy the following two properties

1. Neither $A$ nor $B$ are the entire complex plane
2. One or both of $A$ or $B$ are not simply connected

One of the guiding principles I have is that the singularity at $z=1$ somehow represents "the point at infinity in the Riemann sphere" and to "treat the entire complex plane as a projective plane in the sense of projective geometry", and that the critical region between $z=0$ and $z=1$ is somehow related to "the topology of the projective plane"

Intuitively, at least for me, the projective plane is a "twisted up 2 dimensional space where you cover a watermelon with cellophane and then twist it off at the top and glue it back together in a non-realistic non-physical way"

[image: Text]

More rigorously, we can represent the topology of the projective plane as a square, or so-called "fundamental rectangle", where the sides of the square are "glued together" in a specific way as shown in this picture

[image: Text]

I just had the most strange idea which is to try and make the singularity of the zeta-function at $z=1$ a point at infinity in the projective plane, and to try and map the critical strip to the so-called "twist off" section of the projective plane which results from "gluing together" the fundamental rectangle in the described way

There are many reasons I was led to this kind of approach, but at this time I have no idea if anyone has ever tried this before, or if this is a very bad/silly idea that won't work.  I will only provide one more piece of information about the motivation at this time, feel free to ask if you are curious in the comments.

The basic idea is to figure out if it's possible to show that the critical line, $Im(z)=\frac{1}{2}$, corresponds somehow to the "line at infinity" in the projective plane

(EDIT: Here is one way to view the complex plane as a projective plane: consider a 3-dimensional real space and imagine a unit sphere centered at the origin. Construct the projective plane using the standard definition of the set of all lines passing through the origin. Project all points of 3-d space onto the surface of this sphere with this construction in a 2-1 way; then project all the  points on the surface of this sphere (except for one) onto the complex plane using the Riemann sphere projection.)

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, and yes everything that is possible on $\zeta(s)$ has been tried, up to a certain level of difficulty. The basic example of a Dirichlet series having all its zeros on a line is $1-2^{-s}$.

Comment: @reuns I am confused by your comment.  You stated "Your understanding is wrong" but my understanding is that I must be confused about something and was hoping someone could provide a reference.  Clearly you are not suggesting I am wrong about me thinking I would like a reference, right?  Which part of my question are you referring to when you say my "understanding is wrong"?  I find your comment "yes everything that is possible on () has been tried, up to a certain level of difficulty" confusing as well.  If this has been tried, do you know any references I can read?  Thanks

Comment: @MattCalhoun (1) what is confusing about "yes everything that is possible on () has been tried, up to a certain level of difficulty"? (2) I'm not sure what Reuns was referring to, but you make claims in your post about what projective planes are to you intuitively.

Comment: @mathworker21 I found it confusing because I don't believe the commenter had properly understood that my question was fundamentally the following: "My understanding must be wrong, hasn't everything that is possible on () has been tried, up to a certain level of difficulty?  Does anyone have a reference for this simple idea? [Explain Idea]" I only claimed what I find intuitive, is that a problem? Its especially confusing because if this has been tried already, why has this question been up for 4+ days and has 0 links to any references? That's what I find very strange.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @MattCalhoun No. That statement is a statement independent of your question. Also, it's not a problem for you to claim what you find intuitive, but it perfectly allows someone to say "your understanding is wrong". In regards to why no references, I (and probably many others) only have a nonconstructive 'proof' that everything related to the $\zeta$ function has been tried, since it's been around for so long and is very important.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am not comfortable taking on blind faith that everything has been tried up to a certain difficulty, since this would imply it's totally pointless to try and invent new proof strategies.  I would be much more comfortable if someone said, yes this idea has been tried and this is where these ideas go and here is a paper about it, or "no it's not been tried, why don't you go for it?".  I don't enjoy being told the thing I have been working hard on for 3 days is completely pointless when I came here to ask for a reference.  It's fine. I will just keep going if no one has a reference

Comment: @MattCalhoun I don't think "everything" literally means "everything". But to try to say something radically new about the $\zeta$ function, you need a really, really brand new idea. Look, obviously it's possible to have a new idea, but with insanely, insanely high probability, you did not, and your hard work for 3 days was completely pointless. But by "completely pointless", I just mean in terms of tangible progress. I hope you learn a lot from your endeavors. But at some point, one must get a feel for what things will apriori probably not work due to a problem's fame.

Comment: @mathworker21 I agree with you!!!! This is very well stated by you, imo.  However, since I just play around with this stuff for fun when I am bored as a mental exercise, and have no illusions about actually coming up with a new proof strategy, its really fine and I don't consider it a waste of time at all. I think others should have this kind of playful attitude, and apologize for miscommunicating my question in that sense. I think the idea that the line at infinity in the projective plane goes over to the critical line is wild, and I have been working on formal geometrical/topological ideas

Comment: @MattCalhoun Awesome. I guess the issue is that there are hundreds, if not thousands, of cranks that think they proved, or are on a route to proving, RH, so I think many people (such as Reuns) have been accustomed to letting them know they that most likely won't prove RH. I'm always happy to see passionate people playing around with stuff, trying to learn. Have fun!!